# Run sbt with -Ylog-classpath

Tags: scala, sbt

I got an error like this when I run 'sbt compile':

```
missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'DefaultReads.class'.
[error] Could not access term time in package java,
[error] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
[error] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
```

How can I pass `-Ylog-classpath` to sbt?

Answer (score 29):

`-Y` is just a `scalac` parameter. There are two types as per the [doc](https://fossies.org/windows/misc/scala-2.11.6.zip/scala-2.11.6/man/man1/scalac.1) `-Y` being private and `-X` being advanced. The difference is that private ones can be removed without prior notice and you should be aware of that fact.

To add `scalac` options add to your `build.sbt` file this line:

```
scalacOptions += "-Ylog-classpath"
```

Similarly you can add `javac` options with `javacOptions`.