# Using sbt to package scala source code in cmd : error missing 'SparkContext.class'

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I'm new for spark, following [tutorial](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html) to learn. I have installed 
**openjdk version "1.8.0_121"(web-binary) 
Hadoop 2.8.0 (web-binary)
scala version 2.11.8 (apt)
and spark version 2.1.1 (web-binary-pre-build-with-hadoop 2.6.0 or later).**

I runned SparkPi example and successed. But, some error appears, when I try to package my first spark app with **sbt 0.13.15(apt)**, which was installed by the way [org said](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html).

I know must be a mistake about settings somewhere, but fail to find out in [this link](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Library-Dependencies.html). Could anyone help me? Thanks :)

My project is like :

```
---SparkApp
  |---simple.sbt
  |---src
      |---main
          |---scala
              |--- SimpleApp.scala
```

The dot sbt file in my project is :

```
name := "Simple Project"

version := "0.13.15"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.1"
```

Error Log is like this :

```
hadoop@master:~/Mycode/SparkApp$ sbt package
[warn] Executing in batch mode.
[warn]   For better performance, hit [ENTER] to switch to interactive mode, or
[warn]   consider launching sbt without any commands, or explicitly passing 'shell'
[info] Loading project definition from /home/hadoop/Mycode/SparkApp/project
[info] Set current project to Simple Project (in build file:/home/hadoop/Mycode/SparkApp/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/hadoop/Mycode/SparkApp/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'SparkContext.class'.
[error] Could not access term akka in package <root>,
[error] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
[error] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'SparkContext.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of <root>.
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed May 16, 2017 1:08:53 PM
```

Some hints might be the problem is :

1. When I type spark-shell, I got this **Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131)** , which is different with when I type java -version **openjdk version "1.8.0_121"**. Would this be the problem?
2. I didn't do anything after install sbt. Should I do something for setting? like let sbt know where my scala and spark is located. How?
3. I didn't have maven, should I?

------------------------ Second edit -------------------

After add -Ylog-classpath in dot sbt file, like [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425311/run-sbt-with-ylog-classpath) said. I got a very long classpath print out which is too long to show here. **Problem unsolved yet**.

As noted, I provide the SimpleApp.scala :

```
/* SimpleApp.scala */
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val logFile = "file:///usr/local/spark/README.md" // Should be some file on your system
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
    val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
    val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
    println("Lines with a: %s, Lines with b: %s".format(numAs, numBs))
  }
}
```

Comment: @Rahul Should I try to use Intellij?

Comment: You can try. intelliJ is the best IDE around when it comes to Spark & Scala development and plugins are readily available.

Comment: Also can you please add %provided a the end of your dependency in build.sbt and try? libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.1"  % "provided"

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for your advice, my problem has been solved. I still used your solution in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** If you want to **develop** Spark applications you don't have to install Spark.

Having Spark installed locally does help a lot in your early days as a Spark developer (with tools like `spark-shell` and `spark-submit`), but is **not required** yet **highly recommended**.

In other words, what you've installed as a Spark package has nothing to do with what you can and want to use while developing a Spark application.

In sbt-managed Scala projects, you define what you want to use as a dependency, including Spark dependency, in `libraryDependencies` setting as follows:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.1"
```

And to my great surprise, you did that.

It *appears* that you use two different project directories to explain what you're doing `~/Mycode/SparkApp` (in which you execute `sbt package`) and `---Pro` (of which you show `build.sbt`).

*Assuming* your `simple.sbt` looks as follows:

```
name := "Simple Project"

version := "0.13.15"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.1"
```

I could find one issue *only* which is `version` setting that I *believe* is `0.13.15` to reflect the version of sbt.

Please note that they are **not** in any way related and `version` is the version of your application while the version of sbt to use in the project is defined in `project/build.properties` that (given the latest version of sbt 0.13.15) should be as follows:

```
sbt.version = 0.13.15
```

The issue you face while executing `sbt package` (in `/home/hadoop/Mycode/SparkApp`) is that your application defines dependency on Akka as you can see in the error message:

```
[info] Set current project to Simple Project (in build file:/home/hadoop/Mycode/SparkApp/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/hadoop/Mycode/SparkApp/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'SparkContext.class'.
[error] Could not access term akka in package <root>,
[error] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
[error] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'SparkContext.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of <root>.
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

As of Spark 1.6 or so, Akka is no longer in use by Spark so I *guess* the project *somehow* reference Akka libraries that it should not if they're for Spark.

Lots of guesswork which I *hope* we'll sort out soon.